# How to scrape data from a website when linked to event clicks?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, extract

I am trying to scrape/extract the website of the company/hotel from Tripadvisor.com webpages. I don't see the website url when I inspect the page. Any idea on how I can extract the website url using python?
Apologies in advance as I have only recently started 'web scraping in Python.'
Thank you.

E.g.  Please see the two red arrows in the image. When I select the website link it takes me to 'http://www.i-love-my-india.com/' - which is what I want to extract using Python.

[Tripadvisor url](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g304551-d4590508-Reviews-Ashok_s_Taxi_Tours-New_Delhi_National_Capital_Territory_of_Delhi.html)
[image]

Comment: Since it is javascript rendered page you have to use selenium and then using it obtain the page source . Once you get the page source apply beautiful soup to scrap the element

Comment: Selenium is in-memory browser, it loads all your java script, as your desktop browser does. but I have two more options for you.                                        1. when requesting the web page inspect the page and see all request made by the browser may be you can get the link from where all data is coming.                                                                                                         2.  instead of selenium use splash it also renders all your JS, you can import it in python.

Comment: Let me try and get back to you with what worked. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: I thought execute_script will work on this one but it didnt work.Only solution i think of is to use selenium to click on websitehref tag ,new tab will launch then take the current url of that newest tab using selenium itself.

Comment: This is what I've tried so far. Please click on the link to see the code: [Link_to_the_script](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzcrqcavmiui6dv/tried%20so%20far.txt?dl=0)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one using Selenium :

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Vader\\geckodriver.exe")
# Must install geckodriver (handles your browser)- see instructions on
# http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html.
# Change the path to where your geckodriver file is.

browser.get('https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g304551-d4590508-Reviews-Ashok_s_Taxi_Tours-New_Delhi_National_Capital_Territory_of_Delhi.html')
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.blEntry.website').click()

#browser.window_handles # Results is 2 tabs opened. 

browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[1]) # changes the browser to 
                                                    # the second one

time.sleep(1) # When I went directly I was getting a 'blank' result, so I put
              # a little delay and it worked (I really do not know why).

res = browser.current_url # the URL

print(res)

browser.quit() # Closes the browser
```

[Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html)

Comment: You should fix the error by replacing `browser.find_element_by_class_name('blEntry.website')` with `browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.blEntry.website')` otherwise the code will break. Thanks.

Comment: Well "browser.find_element_by_class_name('blEntry.website').click()" is working for me exactly as it is. Yours suggestion is also working "browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.blEntry.website').click()". But thanks for the alternative.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a look at the element, you'll notice that the redirect URL is there (`data-ahref` attribute), but it's encoded and is decoded somewhere in the JS sources. Unfortunately, they are minified and obfuscated, so finding the decoder function will be hard. You thus have two options:

#### Follow redirects

This is what [Roberval _T_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8333089/roberval-t) suggested in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48597722/2650249): click on the element, wait some time for the page to be loaded in another tab, grab the URL. This is a perfectly valid answer that deserves an upvote in my opinion, however here's a little technique I always try when the desired data is unavailable for some reason:

#### Scrape the mobile webpage

The obvious advantage of scraping the mobile pages is that they are more lightweight than the desktop ones. But often, the mobile website also has the data present when the desktop version tries to hide the data for some reason. In this case, all the infos (address, homepage, phone) in the mobile version can be grabbed immediately without loading the URL explicitly. Here's how the page looks like when I run selenium with a mobile user agent:

[image]

An example code using IPhone's user agent:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = 'https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g304551-d4590508-Reviews-Ashok_s_Taxi_Tours-New_Delhi_National_Capital_Territory_of_Delhi.html'
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get(url)

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.website.contact_link')
link = element.text
driver.quit()
print(link)
```

Comment: Thanks @hoefling - I used the approach by  Roberval _T_ because it will work with every scenario. But I want to thank you for the 'mobile page' approach. If i fall into a similar problem at some point, will keep your suggestion handy.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using selenium.

My answer can be seen as a improvement on what @Roberval *T* suggested. I consider his answer very good for this particular case.

This is my solution. I will point out some of the differences and why I think you should consider them:

```
import sys

# Selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


# I would use argparse for example
try:
    assert len(sys.argv) == 2
    url = sys.argv[1]
except AssertionError:
    # Invalid arguments
    sys.exit()

# Set up the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

# Try to load the page a wait until it's loaded
try:
    poll_frequency = 5
    data_section_id = "taplc_location_detail_header_attractions_0"
    data_section = WebDriverWait(driver, poll_frequency).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, data_section_id)))
except TimeoutException:
    # Could not load page
    sys.exit()

# Get the third child ( relative to the data section div that we get by ID )
try:
    third_child = data_section.find_elements_by_xpath("./*")[2]
except IndexError:
    sys.exit()

# Get the child immediatly under that ( that's how the structure looks)
container_div = third_child.find_elements_by_xpath("./*")[0]
clickable_element = container_div.find_elements_by_xpath("./*")[3]

# Click the node
clickable_element.click()

# Switch tabs
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

try:
    new_page = WebDriverWait(driver, poll_frequency).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "body")))
except TimeoutError:
    sys.exit()

print(driver.current_url)
assert driver.current_url == "http://www.i-love-my-india.com/"

driver.quit()
```

1. First, in my opinion, you should use `selenium's` specific waiting mechanisms instead of `time.sleep()`. This will allow you to better fine tune your scraper and it will also make it more reliable. I would suggest you look into `WebDriverWait`
2. Second, my personal preference is to avoid using `class selectors`. I am not saying they are wrong. But experience has showed me they can change easily and often times the same class is used in multiple places ( that's why it's a class ). In this particular case, selecting using the `CSS class` works because that class is used in a single place.

   - What happens if in the next release, the same class is used in another place?
   - While following the structure is no guarantee either, it's probably less likely to change.
3. Use `Chrome`. Since version `59`, Google Chrome has a `headless` option. It is much easier to work with then `Firefox`, in my opinion. Going with `Firefox` will require you to install and run a `x server` service on the production machine and connect the `Firefox` instance to that server through the `geckodriver`. You skip all this with `Chrome`.

---

I hope this helps!